# Utilizar retorno de um método em outro método da mesma classe

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, python-3.x, api

Estou trabalhando com a API do The Guardian, através de dois métodos, `search_content()` e `data_to_csv()`, contidos na classe TheGuardian. O primeiro método é responsável por pesquisar na base de dados do The Guardian de acordo com os parâmetros fornecidos, enquanto que o segundo, consolida os dados coletados na pesquisa em um arquivo CSV.

Minha dúvida é a seguinte, o método `search_content()` retorna a variável `json_content`, que é um dicionário contendo o pacote de resposta proveniente da pesquisa. Contudo, não estou conseguindo acessar o dicionário no método `data_to_csv()`. Como pode se observar a seguir:

```
>>> from script_guardian import TheGuardian
>>> tg = TheGuardian('2016-01-01', '2018-01-01')
>>> json_content = tg.search_content('education', 'relevance', 'education')
>>> json_content
<bound method Content.get_content_response of <theguardian.theguardian_content.Content object at 0x7f7bb9764c88>>
>>> type(json_content)
<class 'method'>
```

Ou seja, o retorno do método `search_content()` é `<class 'method'>` ao invés de Dict.

Acredito que este problema é decorrente da forma como organizei meus métodos. Se no momento de instanciar o objeto, eu executo o método `data_to_csv()`, consigo atualizar o arquivo csv, desta forma:

```
tg.data_to_csv(search_content())
```

Gostaria de saber como posso organizar meu código de forma a executar os métodos, no momento da criação do objeto, somente com os parâmetros 'data_inicial' e 'data_final'. Ou seja,

```
tg = TheGuardian('yyyy-mm-dd','yyyy-mm-dd')
```

Acredito que isso possa ser configurado no `__init__`, mas não sei como.

Dúvidas:

- Como executar métodos automaticamente ao criar objeto?
- Como receber json_content no método `data_to_csv()` no formato Dict, ao invés do método por si?

Meu código:

```
from theguardian import theguardian_content
import csv


class TheGuardian(object):
    '''Metodos para busca e conversao de dados na base do The Guardian'''

    def __init__(self, data_inicial, data_final):
        '''
        Inicializacao da instancia

        Args:
            data_inicial(str): data no formato ISO 8601
            data_final(str): data no formato ISO 8601
        '''
        self.data_inicial = data_inicial
        self.data_final = data_final
        self.data_to_csv(self.search_content())

    def search_content(self, content='education', order_by='relevance',
                       section='education', api_key='test', page_size=10):
        '''
        Metodo responsavel por buscar na base de dados do The Guardian

        Args:
            content(str): as noticias serao relacionadas ao assunto informado
            page_size(str): noticias retornadas por pagina
            order_by(int): ordenacao das noticias, pode ser 'newest',
                           'relevance' e 'oldest'.
            api_key(str): chave da API a ser utilizada
            section(str): secao referente as noticias a serem retornadas

        Returns:
            json_content(dict): pacote de resposta da busca performada
        '''

        self.content = content
        self.page_size = page_size
        self.order_by = order_by
        self.api_key = api_key
        self.section = section

        # Parametros de busca
        params = {
            'data_inicial': self.data_inicial,
            'data_final': self.data_final,
            'order-by': self.order_by,
            'page-size': self.page_size,
            'q': self.content,
            'api': self.api_key,
            'section': self.section
        }

        content = theguardian_content.Content(**params)
        self.json_content = content.get_content_response


    def data_to_csv(self, json_content):
        '''
        Conversao do pacote de resposta da busca em arquivo no formato CSV

        Note:
            Arquivo guardian_data.csv sera reescrito apos cada consulta na API

        Args:
            json_content(dict): conteudo retornado a partir dos parametros de
                                busca informados anteriormente

        Returns:
            guardian_data(csv): consolidacao dos dados consultado na API
        '''

        with open('guardian_data.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
            writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')

            # Escricao do cabecalho do arquivo CSV
            writer.writerow(["webUrl", "webPublicationDate", "webTitle",
                             "sectionName", "apiUrl", "id", "isHosted",
                             "sectionId", "type", "pillarId", "pillarName"])

            for result in self.json_content['response']['results']:
                writer.writerow([
                    result["webUrl"],
                    result["webPublicationDate"],
                    result["webTitle"],
                    result["sectionName"],
                    result["apiUrl"],
                    result["id"],
                    result["isHosted"],
                    result["sectionId"],
                    result["type"],
                    result["pillarId"],
                    result["pillarName"]
                ])
```

Answer (score 1):

Você poderia jogar a saída de um método na entrada do outro mas isto não é lá muito bonito (tipo, a informação sai do objeto e depois entra). Ah sim, para executar métodos ao criar um objeto basta chamá-los dentro do construtor, o **__init__()**.

Já que *json_content* é um atributo da classe, inicialize-o dentro de **__init__()** com `self.json_content = {}`. Finalize o método **search_content()** com `self.json_content = content.get_content_response()` e altere **data_to_csv()** para não receber outros parâmetros além do *self* e remova o `self.json_content = json_content`.

Comment: Se o data_to_csv só recebe self, como eu posso passar o json_content?

Comment: Não há necessidade de passar o _json_content_ pois ele já está dentro do _self_.

Comment: Atualizei o código acima, contudo ainda estou recebendo "method object is not subscriptable" após rodar tg = TheGuardian(data1, data2)

Comment: É `return content.get_content_response()`, precisa ter os dois parênteses. Quando escrevi minha solução eu deixei escapar, então me desculpe (vou aproveitar para corrigir lá também).